# Identity Server 4 star ssl certificate for demo

Tags: ssl, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Is it possible to find a free star certificate compatible with all Identity Server 4 samples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change identity server configuration to use

```
 X509Certificate2 signingCertificate = null;
        using (var certStore = new X509Store(storeName: "My",
            storeLocation: StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            signingCertificate = certStore.Certificates.Find(findType: X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                findValue: Regex.Replace(input: serverOptions.CertificateThumbPrint, pattern: @"[^\da-zA-z]", replacement: string.Empty).ToUpper(),
                validOnly: true).Count > 0 ?
                certStore.Certificates.Find(findType: X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                findValue: Regex.Replace(input: serverOptions.CertificateThumbPrint, pattern: @"[^\da-zA-z]",
                replacement: string.Empty).ToUpper(),
                validOnly: true)[0] : null;
        }


    .AddSigningCredential(signingCertificate)
```